# "if - elseif - then - else" statement is not working

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have three texboxes, called tbttUg1,tbttUg2 and tbttUg3. The basic is, that when i click on a "Add" button, the first textbox shows a result of an equestion. When I click the second time on it, the second textbox shows a result.

the code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim bb As Integer
Dim dt As Integer

bb = tbttA.Value / (0.5 * tbttP.Value)
dt = tbttw.Value + cbttL.Value * (0.17 + 1 / tbttU.Value)
mif = 2 * cbttL.Value / (3.1415 * bb + dt) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(3.1415 * bb / dt + 1) 
wif = cbttL.Value / (0.457 * bb + dt) 

If tbttUg1.Value = "" And dt < bb Then
        tbttUg1.Value = Round(mif, 4)
ElseIf tbttUg1.Value = "" And dt >= bb Then
        tbttUg1.Value = Round(wif, 4)
ElseIf tbttUg1.Value > 0 And dt < bb Then
        tbttUg2.Value = Round(mif, 4)
ElseIf tbttUg1.Value > 0 And dt >= bb Then
        tbttUg2.Value = Round(wif, 4)
ElseIf tbttUg2.Value > 0 And dt < bb Then
        tbttUg3.Value = Round(mif, 4)
ElseIf tbttUg2.Value > 0 And dt >= bb Then
        tbttUg3.Value = Round(wif, 4)
        Else
        MsgBox "halo"
End If

End Sub
```

The problems it, that adding works only for two texboxes, I don't know why, but the third adding always re-writes the second one.

Does anyone sees the mistake in coding?

Furthermore, is there any better way for adding ans seeing an interim result on a single userform
page?

Thanks for any kind of feedback!

Comment: Try using select...Case statment rather than the massive If...ElseIf

Comment: It's too many conditions to get all this correctly inserted in "Case statement". Probably it can be done, but it's quite confusing. If is perfect for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really clarifies your code if you split off the `mif`/`wif` stuff, and just have one `If` statement for each box. Does this work instead?

```
Dim DispText As String
DispText = Round(IIf(dt < bb, mif, wif), 4)

If Len(tbttUg1.Value) = 0 Then
    tbttUg1.Value = DispText
ElseIf Len(tbttUg2.Value) = 0 Then
    tbttUg2.Value = DispText
ElseIf Len(tbttUg3.Value) = 0 Then
    tbttUg3.Value = DispText
Else
    MsgBox "halo"
End If
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfect! Many thanks @rdhs! I didn't know about the Len function, but DispText probably saves the day. I don't know, maybe too many statements was the reason for an error before. Your suggestions works great. Thanks!

Comment: @rhds On follow up question. Do you perhaps know, if I use values from input TextBoxes and use them in a calculation, where I multiply them, they lose their decimal point. E.g. values 10,22*15,66 = 1600452. Is that the consequence of incorrect definition of textboxes?

Comment: Do you get different results if you explicitly wrap the numbers in `CDbl`?

Comment: @rhds No. It's strange. I try to multiply a value from combobox and textbox (e.g. let's say 1,5*1,5). If i try only a command  tbttHg1.Value = cbttL.Value you get 1,5 (and not 15), and if you try tbttHg1.Value = CDbl(tbttA.Value) you get 1,5 (and not 15). But if you try tbttHg1.Value = cbttL.Value * CDbl(tbttA.Value) you get - 22.5. I tried several combinations but with no solution so far.

Comment: Same goes for tbttHgm1.Value = CDbl(cbttL.Value) * CDbl(tbttA.Value) of course.  I tried several combinations but with no solution so far.

Comment: I tried this and it works: tbttHgm1.Value = Replace(cbttL.Value, ".", ",") * CDbl(tbttA.Value) , which basically means that I change the value from combobox from "1.5" to "1,5" and then multiply it with "1,5" from the textbox, as a result I get "2.25". Don't know why... again. Strange:)